# OnCollisionEnter2D making my object to disappear from game screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a turret ,which is a game object,i have built a box collider around it to detect collision,if my enemy enters the boxcollider of the turet ,it aims at it and shoots it,but for some reason,the turret gets disappeared after enemy enters the collision box.,and also the shooting is ain't visible.where am i wrong,any help ,thanx!!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TurretScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float shotInterval = 0.2f; // interval between shots
public Rigidbody2D bulletPrefab; // drag the bullet prefab here

private float shootTime = 0.0f;
private List<Transform> targets;
private Transform selectedTarget;
private Transform myTransform;
private Transform bulletSpawn;

void Start(){
    targets = new List<Transform>();
    selectedTarget = null;
    myTransform = transform;
    bulletSpawn = transform.Find ("bulletSpawn"); // only works if bulletSpawn is a turret child!
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "enemy"){ // only enemies are added to the target list!
        targets.Add(other.transform);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "enemy"){
        targets.Remove(other.transform);
    }
}

void TargetEnemy(){
    if (selectedTarget == null){ // if target destroyed or not selected yet...
        SortTargetsByDistance();  // select the closest one
        if (targets.Count > 0) selectedTarget = targets[0];
        Debug.Log ("selected target is"+selectedTarget);
    }
}

void SortTargetsByDistance(){
    targets.Sort(delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2){ 
        return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

void Update(){
    TargetEnemy(); // update the selected target and look at it
    if (selectedTarget)
   { 
        // if there's any target in the range...
        transform.LookAt(selectedTarget); // aim at it
        if (Time.time >= shootTime){// if it's time to shoot...
            Rigidbody2D bullet = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
            bullet.AddForce(transform.forward*5); // shoot in the target direction
            shootTime = Time.time + shotInterval; // set time for next shot
        }
    }
}
  }
```

here is enemy code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float speed = 2f;

public int Health;

public float GetHealth()
{
    return Health; 
}


    void Update ()
    {
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed     * Time.deltaTime);                                                                     
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damage){
    Health -= damage;
    if (Health <= 0) 
        Destroy(gameObject);
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
{
    PlayerControl shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
    if (shot != null)
    {
        SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);
        Destroy(shot.gameObject); 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I have updated the enemyscript,there is no error.

Comment: no,player is different its a part of game having a player,and the turret is not disappearing from the hiararchy aslo,it is there,i saw in scene,its rotating and aiming towards the enemy,and the shooting also,because the enemy die,and the bullets are also not visible.,surely i have done some silly mistake.

Comment: i cant see it in the "game",in the "scene" its showing up means, its y axis getting set to greater than 90 degree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66634/discussion-between-safwan-and-k4rlsson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform.LookAt is rotating your go which makes you unable to see it.

try rotating it like this instead :

```
Vector3 dir = selectedTarget.position - transform.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: the bullets are just coming out ,not moving toward the enemy.,is there any problem in the bullets?

Comment: is there any way to control the speed of the turrets aiming movement?

Comment: its another problem with bullet.,and why the transform.LookAt didnt worked?

Comment: but my bullet is not moving forward,i have instantiated the code in the turret class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66639/discussion-between-safwan-and-k4rlsson).